# Proof of completeness of the set of natural numbers

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum, natural-numbers

> If $A (\subset \mathbb{N})$ is non-empty and bounded above, then $A$ has its supremum in $\mathbb{N}$.

It is clear intuitively, but I cannot understand how to prove it. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried using induction?

Comment: Prove the contrapositive. Assume $A$ has no supremum (write down what that means, using the definition of a supremum). Prove by induction that, for all $n\in\Bbb N$, there exists $m\in A$ with $m\ge n$. Explain why this contadicts $A$ being bounded.